# In Spring, is there a way I can find a route by name?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Is there a way I can find a route by name? I am using the latest spring-boot.

Given:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/list", name = "list")
public String list() { ... }
```

I would like to be able to run something like:

```
route = getRouteByName("list")
```

I develop a Thymeleaf tag processor and I want to be able to create the URL in . It would be quite handy to use "name" parameter of @Route. I try to make the tag look like: Text

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the use-case of having something like `route = getRouteByName("list")`? What would be done with `route` then?

Comment: I develop a Thymeleaf tag processor and I want to be able to create the URL in <a href="..">. It would be quite handy to use "name" parameter of @Route. 

I try to make the tag look like: <a x:to="list" x:page="2" x:sort="asc">Text</a>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you intend to build a url out of the `name` of the mapping, you can do it using the `fromMappingName(String mappingName)` method of `MvcUriComponentsBuilder`. Documentation of the same [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/MvcUriComponentsBuilder.html#fromMappingName-java.lang.String-).

```
String url = MvcUriComponentsBuilder.fromMappingName("list").build();
```

PS: You might need some more configurations in the builder to form your complete url though. The above example is just to ensure brevity.

Comment: I ran into another issue: MvcUriComponentsBuilder.fromMappingName("list").buildAndExpand() does not accept a map as argument, the same as UriComponentsBuilder.buildAndExpand does.

Comment: @user3429660 yeah it doesn't have a signature that accepts a map. Probably you can try the `fromMethod(Class<?> controllerType, Method method, Object... args)` method and pass the controller type and method name which returns a `UriComponentsBuilder`.

Comment: @user3429660 or you can use the `fromMappingName(UriComponentsBuilder builder, String name)` method of `MvcUriComponentsBuilder `, passing a `UriComponentsBuilder` object with `uriVariables(Map<String,Object> uriVariables)`.

Comment: @user3429660 did that help?

Comment: I'm still digging through UriComponentsBuilder and friends, but you put me on the right track. Thanks.

Comment: @user3429660 happy to help :)