# MvcUriComponentsBuilder to generate a url from named routes with parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I just started with Spring Boot and I would like to generate a URL based on named routes. I was able to start my code halfway using the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57055314/13933721). However, the route has a parameter and I want to include that in my generated route:

AuthenticationController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/v1/auth", name = "auth")
public class AuthenticationController {

    @PostMapping(path = "/password-change/{token}", name = "passwordChange")
    public void passwordChange(@PathVariable("token") String token){
    }

}
```

The method somewhere.java

```
String url = MvcUriComponentsBuilder.fromMappingName("auth#passwordChange").build();
```

With or without the `{token}` in the path, the url value is always `"/api/v1/auth/password-change/"`. How should I generate the full url using the name route?

I also tried using the `buildAndExpand` method still the same result:

```
String url = MvcUriComponentsBuilder
        .fromMappingName("auth#passwordChange")
        .buildAndExpand("token1234")
        .toString();
```

My expected result should be `"/api/v1/auth/password-change/token1234"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. The code needed is:

```
String url = MvcUriComponentsBuilder
        .fromMappingName(ControllerName.class, "methodName", "param1") // where starting from "param1" can be multiple params separated by comma「,」
        .toString();
```

Now for my question, the actual code would be:

```
# /api/v1/auth/password-change/token1234
String url = MvcUriComponentsBuilder
        .fromMappingName(AuthenticationController.class, "passwordChange", "token1234")
        .toString();
```

If you need multiple parameters then:

```
# /api/v1/auth/xxxx/{param1}/yyyy/{param2}
# becomes
# /api/v1/auth/xxxx/param1Val/yyyy/param2Val
String url = MvcUriComponentsBuilder
        .fromMappingName(ControllerName.class, "methodName", "param1Val", "param2Val")
        .toString();
```